# Node.js stack-size silently crashing

Tags: node.js, windows, stack-overflow, callstack

I have a JavaScript commandline program that needs more stack space. The option for this is `node --stack-size` but it's not working for me. Test case:

```
'use strict'

function f(...a) {
    console.log(a[0] + a[a.length - 1])
}

var a = []
for (var i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
    a.push(i)
}
f(...a)
```

Run with plain `node`, the above crashes with an error message saying maximum call stack size exceeded. But run with `node --stack-size=10000` (specifying ten megabytes of stack space, which should be enough) it just exits silently without printing any output, not even an error message.

I'm using Node 14.16.1 x64 on Windows 10.

What am I doing wrong?

`echo %errorlevel%` shows -1073741571, which is C00000FD, which is indeed the Windows error code for a stack overflow.

Comment: But _why_ splat `a` into arguments instead of just using it as an array?

Comment: @AKX It's a test case. You wouldn't appreciate if I dumped a couple of thousand lines of code from the real program into the question text.

Comment: Sure. Why does the real program need to splat an array into arguments when it can just use it as an array?

Comment: @AKX Outside the scope of this question. Seriously, an architecture document explaining the design of the program wouldn't fit in the comments. If I were asking for advice on the program design, that would be a separate question in its own right.

Comment: Sorry if this sounds confrontational, but I think your program design may be wrong if you need to set an interpreter flag to expand stack size to correctly run it.

Comment: @AKX I have no objection to you holding that opinion. I believe in freedom of thought! But the comments section of a stack overflow question is not the place to debate questions of software architecture.

Comment: You might be running into the parameter count limitation, which is probably below 1 million.